# git establecer un segundo origen a mi repo

Tags: git

Quisiera tener una **verisón de paga** y una **versipon gratis** de la misma aplicación, y para ello pienso usar **un repositorio público** y **uno privado** en [github](/questions/tagged/github), y quisiera poder pasar los commits de un proyecto a otro.

Para ello quisiera optar por la opción de establecer un segundo `remote` a mi código fuente como lo sugieren [en esta respuesta de SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703238/6999690), pero no sé como se haría eso si un set origin borraría el primero, etc ¿Cómo podría entonces poner dos orígenes a mi código fuente con la finalidad de tener un `branch` privado solo en el repositorio privado?.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes tener varios *remotes* configurados en un solo repositorio local. Podrías crear el que será el repositorio *privado* en el proveedor y, una vez que tengas el URL al repositorio, lo agregas como remoto al local... en este caso lo llamaré `privado`:

```
git remote add privado url-del-repositorio
```

Luego de eso, podrías tener una rama, llamémosla `privada` que tiene todas las cosas del *main branch* mas los ajustes que quieres hacer en la versión que solo es *paga*. Podrias colocar el upstream de la rama privada:

```
git checkout privada
git branch --set-upstream privado/privada # privado es el remoto, privada es la rama
```

Luego solo tienes que empujar al repositorio adecuado en la rama privada:

```
# ya estando en la rama privada:
git push # como ya el upstream está puesto, eso hace toda la magia de empujar al repo adecuado
```

Y listo.